# How to determine if the file was modified when exiting vim?

Tags: perl, vim

I'm invoking vim editor from perl program in such a way:

```
my $cmd = "vi myfile";
system($cmd);
```

Then I'd like to perform different action according as file was modified or not:

```
if(myfile was modified) {
    doAction1;
}
else {
    doAction2;
}
```

How to check if file was modified or not? I searched for vim exit codes but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 4):

The easy way is to check file's `mtime`:

```
my $old_mtime = (stat $file)[9];
system( 'vi', $file );
if ( (stat $file)[9] != $old_mtime ) {
    # file modified
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a script that introduces a tmp file:

```
MYTMP=/tmp/perltimestamp.$$
file=myfile
touch ${MYTMP}
vi ${file}
if [ $(find . -name ${file} -newer ${MYTMP} | wc -l ) -gt 0 ]; then
   rm ${MYTMP}
   doAction1
} else {
   rm ${MYTMP}
   doAction2;
}
```

Of course you can move the rm command outside the if-then-else, when your doActions are quick and safe.

Answer (score 0):

The [`File::Modified` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Modified/lib/File/Modified.pm) encapsulates MD5 and mtime checks (preferring MD5 if `File::MD5` is installed):

```
use File::Modified;
my $detector = File::Modified->new(files=>[$filename]);
# [run the editor]
if($detector->changed) { # [...]
```

Here is a complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Modified;

my $filename = 'myfile';
my $detector = File::Modified->new(files=>[$filename]);

my $cmd = "vi $filename";
system $cmd;

if($detector->changed) {
    print "modified\n";
} else {
    print "the same\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very easy to find in the online help, but there is a way to exit non zero. It is hidden in the quickfix help, which might also be interesting to someone looking for this answer.

see `:help cquit`, or `:help quickfix` for iteration goodies.
*Note, This depends on the quickfix feature, check for it in `:version`.

The most basic way to do this then is to use two different ways to exit. `:wq` if you want to write the file, and `:cq` if not (unfortunately, `:cq` does not offer an option to save the file). Using different exit strategies does have it's benefits. If I get into the file and realize that I do not wish for the automated task to run after all, I can do `:w` `:cq`

Deciding how to exit though, is one more decision that nobody needs. The following key map makes life easy.
Just `Ctrl + x` to exit.

```
:map <C-X> <ESC>:if &modified \| wq \| else \| cq \| endif <CR>
:imap <C-X> <ESC>:if &modified \| wq \| else \| cq \| endif <CR>
```

The caveat here is that the file may not be different even if the modified flag is set, see `:help modified`.

Beware, if you do not already have a `vimrc` file, you will need to port one in that doesn't break vim into compatibility mode. Something like `cp /etc/vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc`